# We migrated our app from Parse to Azure but the costs of DocumentDB is so high. Are we doing something wrong?

Tags: azure, parse-platform, azure-cosmosdb

We migrated our mobile app (still being developed) from Parse to Azure. Everything is running, but the price of DocumentDB is so high that we can't continue with Azure without fix that. Probably we're doing something wrong.

1) Price seams to have a bottleneck in the DocumentDB requests.

Running a process to load the data (about 0.5 million documents), memory and CPU was ok, but the DocumentDB request limit was a bottleneck, and the price charged was very high.

2) Even after the end of this data migration (few days of processing), azure continue to charge us every day.

We can't understand what is going on here. The graphic for use are flat, but the price is still climbing, as you can see in the imagens.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image: Requests]

[image: Costs]

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshots, you have 15 collections under the Parse database. With Parse: Aside from the system classes, each of your user-defined classes gets stored in its own collection. And given that each (non-partitioned) collection has a starting run-rate of ~$24/month (for an S1 collection), you can see where the baseline cost would be for 15 collections (around $360).

You're paying for reserved storage and RU capacity. Regardless of RU utilization, you pay whatever the cost is for that capacity (e.g. S2 runs around $50/month / collection, even if you don't execute a single query). Similar to spinning up a VM of a certain CPU capacity and then running nothing on it.

Answer (score 0):

The default throughput setting for the parse collections is set to 1000 RUPS. This will cost $60 per collection (at the rate of $6 per 100 RUPS). Once you finish the parse migration, the throughput can be lowered if you believe the workload decreased. This will reduce the charge.

To learn how to do this, take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-performance-levels/ (Changing the throughput of a Collection).

The key thing to note is that DocumentDB delivers predictable performance by reserving resources to satisfy your application's throughput needs. Because application load and access patterns change over time, DocumentDB allows you to easily increase or decrease the amount of reserved throughput available to your application.

Answer (score -1):

Azure is a "pay-for-what-you-use" model, especially around resources like DocumentDB and SQL Database where you pay for the level of performance required along with required storage space.  So if your requirements are that all queries/transactions have sub-second response times, you may pay more to get that performance guarantee (ignoring optimizations, etc.)

One thing I would seriously look into is the [DocumentDB Cost Estimation tool](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner#); this allows you to get estimates of throughput costs based upon transaction types based on sample JSON documents you provide:

[image]

So in this example, I have an 8KB JSON document, where I expect to store 500K of them (to get an approx. storage cost) and specifying I need throughput to create 100 documents/sec, read 10/sec, and update 100/sec (I used the same document as an example of what the update will look like).

NOTE this needs to be done PER DOCUMENT -- if you're storing documents that do not necessarily conform to a given "schema" or structure *in the same collection*, then you'll need to repeat this process for *EVERY* type of document.

Based on this information, I cause use those values as inputs into the pricing calculator.  This tells me that I can estimate about $450/mo for DocumentDB services alone (if this was my anticipated usage pattern).

[image]

There are additional ways you can optimize the Request Units (RUs -- metric used to measure the cost of the given request/transaction -- and what you're getting billed for): optimizing index strategies, optimizing queries, etc.  Review the documentation on [Request Units](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-request-units) for more details.

Comment: I'll keep this answer for reference but it could very well be that you have paid the "penalty" for migrating all your existing data all at once.  Seeing as how there haven't been any additional requests since 8 Aug 2016, you're not paying for any *additional* requests but you still must pay for what you *did use* (the 11Mil RUs to load your data). I hope that make sense